# Random Number Generator in Discord.py

Tags: python, random, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def givenum(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Type a number")
    num1 = ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
    await ctx.send("Type a second, larger number")
    num2 = ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
    try:
        numb1 = int(num1)
        numb2 = int(num2)
        if numb1 < numb2:
            value = random.randint(num1,num2)
            await ctx.send(f"You got {value}.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(":warning: Please ensure the first number is smaller than the second number.")
    except:
        await ctx.send(":warning: Please use positive integers")
```

This is a random number generator for our discord.py bot. When we run this code is says "Type a number" but when we type a number it doesn't send anything. It doesn't even give an error. We are trying to make it respond when its non-prefixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using old documentation from async (v0.16.x), try this from the rewrite docs:

```py
@client.command()
async def givenum(ctx):

    # checks the author is responding in the same channel
    # and the message is able to be converted to a positive int
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.content.isdigit() and \
               msg.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send("Type a number")
    msg1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Type a second, larger number")
    msg2 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    x = int(msg1.content)
    y = int(msg2.content)
    if x < y:
        value = random.randint(x,y)
        await ctx.send(f"You got {value}.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(":warning: Please ensure the first number is smaller than the second number.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
- [`.isdigit()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp)

Comment: It says to give the both numbers but it doesn't give the latest answer. I thinks it's because i didn't tell what "num1" and "num2" was

Comment: Sorry, was an issue with my answer, forgot to rename a couple of the variables! Should be working now :^)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to `await` on `ctx.wait_for_message()`. I also took the liberty of fixing things so the bot will sort those two numbers and the user doesn't have to figure out which is smaller.

```py
@client.command()
async def givenum(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Type a number")
    num1 = await ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
    await ctx.send("Type a second number")
    num2 = await ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
    try:
        numb = int(num1)
        numb = int(num2)
        value = random.randint(min(num1, num2), max(num1, num2))
        await ctx.send(f"You got {value}.")
    except:
        await ctx.send(":warning: Please use positive integers")
```